# Help! Grey background on render despite checking 'Transparent' and RGBA

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

So I am trying to render some transparent background things, but anything I try results in a black background for Png, or a grey background for RGBA saved files. I have checked the transparency box under 'Film', ticked the 'use alpha' box in the composite node, etc. I've seen a million threads about this, and but saving as RGBA gives me a grey background. Is there some hidden alpha setting somewhere or something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say you checked the "transparency" box, do you mean the one under _Render Properties > FIlm > Transparent_?

Comment: Hi! Yeah thats the one.

Comment: "turned on the alpha node" - makes no sense. No such thing in Blender. You probably checked "Use Alpha" checkbox on Composite node. Try to use correct terminology, it's impossible to communicate without it.

Comment: Edited it, sorry about that :)

Comment: For the record, there is no hidden alpha setting - by default, blender renders images as RGBA PNG - the only thing necessary for a transparent background is to check the transparent box under film. The "use alpha" is enabled by default in the compositor and should stay enabled (checked) for transparency to work. If this is still giving you a black background, there must be something else at play.

Comment: Object in the background that is hidden in viewport but not for rendering?